# 整数に変換したい

Tags: python

整数に変換する処理のところでエラーが発生し、調べても解決できなかったので質問します

xmin = int(xmlbox.find('xmin').text)
この部分でエラーが発生します。

print(xmlbox.find('xmin').text)
→ 305.53345388788426

数字は入っているのですが、これをint型に直そうとするとエラー
どうすればいいでしょうか

Comment: [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379910)

Comment: thank you, i will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一度float型に変換してからint型にしてはどうでしょうか？

```
int(float('305.53345388788426'))
# 305
```